# Enumerate vs Integer in production

Tags: java, mongodb, performance, enums, code-readability

I'm using java + mongodb.
And I need to do bussiness logic and database logic with day of week.

Consider about performence, readable code, avoiding error, etc

should i create a enum type.

```
public enum DayOfWeek {
    MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY, SUNDAY;
}
```

or use int instead (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using `enum` will increase readability and maintenance will be easier.

I'm not sure how `enum` value is translated by java driver (but I assume that this will be an int as in c#), that means documents will be smaller and search will be easier (comparing `int` is always faster than comparing `strings`).

Using sequence not starting from 1 (as natural) could lead into issues like what is 5? The other thing is that some languages or techniques put Sunday as `0` `1` `7` - so `enum` - backed with integers looks like a better solution.

---

edit

There is a few issues that could be ignored as you have predefined enumeration values. Creating an index on dayOfWeek field will solve problem, data size overhead could be skipped (or if there will be billions of records - then int value should be considered)

Use enumeration as it makes code more readable and easier to maintain/debug.

Comment: atually, when i'd used java + mogodb, enum saved as String.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the Enum values are saved as Strings in mongo docs. Basically for the sake of readability I'd go for enums instead of strings.

It becomes more important, if the same DB is read by another (non-java) app, and in this case it's better not to have cryptic numbers.